# How do you remove a NuGet package from Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-mac

There only seems to be an Add NuGet Package option. No manage or remove option as is available in the Windows edition of Visual Studio.

Comment: There is a [separate extension](https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-extensions) you can install which will provide a way to manage packages for the solution. It has a manage packages dialog where you can add or remove packages from multiple projects in one step. Hopefully at some point Visual Studio for Mac will include this, or something similar, by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove a NuGet package from the Solution window. Expand the Packages folder for your project, select the package, right click and select Remove, or press the delete key.

[image]

Comment: Couldn't find any of these things mentioned (am using VS Community for Mac 2017 version 7.7.3, Build 43)

Comment: @olisteadman I added a screenshot. Hope that helps. I am using the same version you are.